# Simple qst about CSS, px and percentage width mix?! [with image]

Tags: css

I have this little problem:[image]

How do I set the width on the second box in order to fill all the space, counting with the orange box?

Thanks

HTML:

```
 <div class="parent"><div class="orange"></div><div class="blue"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .parent{width:100%;} .orange{width:100px;}
```

The orange and the blue box must be the same, even if they vary in sizes from page to page, pixel perfect if possible.

Comment: you need to show us the html structure of your elements

Comment: Do you need IE7 support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution uses this markup:

```
<div class="complete">
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

You want `.complete` and `.blue` to be non-floating block elements, which will cause them to use up as much width as possible, but you also need `.orange` to float in order to be on the same line as `.blue` and prevent `.blue` from overlapping it by using a hidden overflow.

```
.complete { overflow : hidden }
.orange   { float : left ; width : 100px }
.blue     { overflow : hidden }
```

If you need to leave a small space between orange and blue, add a right margin to the orange box.

Note that with this solution, the blue and orange boxes will have different heights. If you have graphical effects (such as backgrounds) that require boxes to have the same height, you will need more clever CSS.

Comment: That works! thanks. But I would also need to have the both boxes the same height. Orange might be shorter in some cases but the blue also can be in other cases. How might I do?

Comment: I asked my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386171/how-to-ensure-the-background-image-inside-a-div-is-evenly-shown and my JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8f35d79h/5/. Can you please assist with the right image?