# How to ensure the background image inside a DIV is evenly shown

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code in my ASP.net page (I would like it to be responsive):

```
<div class="mobileTabsNav">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 50px; max-height: 50px; background: #00ff00; background: url('/theImages/mobileMWBtn.png'); background-size: cover; text-align: center;">
        PLEASE SIGN IN
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mobileTabsNav
{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 715px)
{
    .mobileTabsNav
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

It seems the bottom portion of the image is getting cut off:

[image]

When I change it to `background-size: 100% 100%;`, the image is stretched too much on certain screen as in the example shown here:

[image]

As you can see the image is distorted.

Is there anyway to ensure the curve is the same across the board of different screen sizes or do I have to add three separate images?

The image being used on the Fiddle:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

```css
.mobileTabsNav
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobileTabsNav">
                        <div style="float: left; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnCbY.png') no-repeat; min-height: 50px; min-width: 10px; max-width: 10px; background-size: contain;">

                        </div>
    <div style="background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPm8.png')"></div>
                        <div style="float: right; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rll1d.png') no-repeat; min-height: 50px; min-width: 10px; max-width: 10px; background-size: contain;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: OMG, hopefully your code doesn't look like this on your website.
Here, you are looking for the css parameter: background-size: contain/cover depend on what you want

Comment: @Romain What you mean by doesn't look like on my website? I will be moving the inline style back to the stylesheet once I have it working correctly. `contain` just added multiple images to fit the DIV and `cover` is what I posted a screenshot of.

Comment: Why not use CSS to give the div a border-radius, which would handle the rounded corners. That way your curved corners will always be present and the correct size.

Comment: To be perfect, a different image as to be render on different handless devices (load quicker). Also, devices have a different resolution. So, detecting the resolution + render the correct image to the device is what should be done. Note: if this is only a little icon, the svg format can be used. Otherwise, your code is good, but far far away from a perfect usability

Comment: @JoshKG The circles are huge and out of proportion for some reason.

Comment: Roll up a fiddle and lets take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fq26y6ad/  (I am not seeing the image for some reason :/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is create a background image that works well as a repeated pattern (tileable) and then use the `border-radius` property to get the rounded corners.

In this method, the dots will always be the same size regardless of the screen size,
and you only need a single image for all devices.

```css
.mobileTabsNav {
}
.mobileTabsNav .inner {
  min-height: 400px; 
  background: #00ff00 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8WDz.png); 
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobileTabsNav">
    <div class="inner">
        PLEASE SIGN IN
    </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, here is how the background might be cropped to get the tiling to look right:

[image]

Comment: @mark audet, the image is overlapping. Thank you for trying though :)

Comment: Do you mean repeating? you still need to tweak the graphic so that it can be tiled properly.

Comment: I was able to display the left and right in a separate images (http://jsfiddle.net/8f35d79h/) and I was wondering if there is a way to repeat the middle image. I want the middle DIV to be responsive. How would I do that?

Comment: I added a snippet to my question and here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8f35d79h/2/

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I don't see the advantage of adding the rounded corners to separate background images when you can simply adjust the border-radius of the block element to which the background image is attached. Perhaps I don't quite understand the nature of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I tried that approach and it comes out like the snippet you posted :/

Comment: Did you try fixing the background image so that is it symmetric both left-right and up-down?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the design of the image and no way to change it. I did however, come close (http://jsfiddle.net/8f35d79h/4/). Just need to figure out how to get the right image to line up and we are golden :). I took the idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398910/simple-qst-about-css-px-and-percentage-width-mix-with-image

Comment: I reviewed your fiddle and came up with a partial fix, http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/su7kznws/ the floated elments have to appear in the correct sequence in the HTML.  You need to make sure that your images are sized carefully to make sure you don't get any whitespace around the edges. I tweaked a few margins to try to compensate, but it still needs some work.

Comment: Changed to this: `margin: 0 8px 0 8px;` and it's working fine for me so far :) Thank you. Doing some more testing now.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference in the two JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/su7kznws/4/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/ecjcLzst/1/ (on the later one I am using stylesheet and for reason the right image is missing)

Comment: Typo in your class name: mbBtnRightSection instead of mbBtnRightSecion